# Undefined variables bootstrap for viewports

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, media-queries, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to get set padding depending on if the viewport is lg or md in bootstrap my code is:

```
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
        #logo-text {
          padding-top: 1.3em; 

        } 
      }

      @media (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
        #logo-text {
          padding-top: 1em;
        }
      }
```

it seems that when i run this it says Undefined variable: "$screen-lg-min". anyone know whats going on here? I checked the bootstrap files and in _variables.scss there is a variable with that name.

This code is written in application.css.sass stylesheet since im using the gem bootstrap-sass

```
    @import 'bootstrap';
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prosto+One);

    body {
      background-color: black;

      .content-wrapper
      {
        position: absolute;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 50em;
        background-color: white;
        margin-top: 6%;
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to set the viewports in the sibling header.css.sass file and my code is

```
header {

  img {

    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;    
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
    #logo-text {
      padding-top: 1.3em; 

    } 
  }

  @media (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
    #logo-text {
      padding-top: 1em;
    }
  }

  #logo-text {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: #403A2C;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  }

  nav ul {

    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;

    li {      

      font-size: 1.5em;    
      float: right;      
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 16% 1em 0 0;
      padding: .5em .5em;           

      a {

        font-family: 'Prosto One';
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #403A2C;
      } 

      a:hover {

        color: #777D95;   
        text-decoration: none;     
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and where is your code, relating to _variables.scss? Same file? Other file that has no access to _variables.scss?

Comment: Added more content to help

Comment: Did you double-check if your variable is set **before** it is used?

Comment: I assumed they are set inside of bootstrap...

Comment: Yes, but those bootstrap sass files must be imported before your code if you compile all the sass into one css file. Please add some information about your sass import structure.

Comment: This is all done in the bootstrap-sass gem I'm fairly sure if thats what you mean. Other then me having to type @import 'bootstrap'; it sets all the variables

Comment: Yes, we need to know about the import structure. We don't know where you're including this header.css.sass - it probably isn't in a place that has access to the bootstrap variables.

Comment: Its in the same folder as application.css.sass which is where the import statment is